# (PureScript) How to create a Union of two separately defined rows of effects

Tags: purescript, set-union

I'm essentially needing to know how to write a function like this...

```
joinCommands :: forall e1 e2 e3
   . Union e1 e2 e3
  => Eff e1 Unit
  -> Eff e2 Unit
  -> Eff e3 Unit
joinCommands fn1 fn2 = do
  fn1
  fn2
```

Which doesn't work.  I get this error:

> [PureScript] Could not match kind
>
> ```
> Control.Monad.Eff.Effect
> ```
>
> with kind
>
> ```
> Type
> ```

More specifically, what I'm trying to do is combine two Arrays of user-supplied functionality.  That is one part of the codebase (user supplied) returns `Array (Eff e1 Unit)` and another part (also user supplied) returns `Array (Eff e2 Unit)`.  And at the application's entrypoint (the "core" unaccessable to the user) those two sets need to combined so they can be run together.  So really, I'm trying to write a function of type `Array (Eff e1 Unit) -> Array (Eff e2 Unit) -> Array (Eff e3 Unit)` where `e3` unites all the effects of `e1` and `e2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  For the general case, I just needed  to specific that each Eff has a type that is compatiable with each other (not necessarily the same).

```
joinCommands :: forall e. Eff e Unit -> Eff e Unit -> Eff e Unit
joinCommands fn1 fn2 = do
  fn1
  fn2
```

For the specific case, the answer is the same.  The function signature would be `forall e. Array (Eff e Unit) -> Array (Eff e Unit) -> Array (Eff e Unit)` and the compiler can work out that the first set of Effs is compatible with the second set.

So if you had...

```
type Commands e = Array (Eff e Unit)
a :: forall e. Commands (random :: RANDOM | e)
a = []

b :: forall e. Commands (now :: NOW | e)
b = []

c :: forall e. Commands e -> Commands e -> Commands e
c = a <> b
```

... you can call `c a b` even though `a` and `b` both have different explicit effects.